# React Redux Toolkit: TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of undefined

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-toolkit

In my project I have implemented React Redux toolkit for 2 different states scenarios and they work perfectly. Now I needed to implement a 3rd state scenario for Redux, so I've followed the same pattern as for the first 2. Inspired from: https://react-redux.js.org/tutorials/quick-start

My 3rd state scenario has the following slice declaration:

```
import { createSlice } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";

export const betsSlice = createSlice({
  name: "bets",
  initialState: { value: { betsLeft: 0, betToBet: 0, usersBets: "" } },
  reducers: {
    updateBets: (state, action) => {
      state.value = action.payload;
    },
  },
});

export const { updateBets } = betsSlice.actions;

/**
 * Exporting to avoid boilerplate like:
 * const count = useSelector((state) => state.counter.value)
 */
export const getBets = (state) => state.bets.value;

export default betsSlice.reducer;
```

The store.js:

```
import { configureStore } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import themeModeReducer from "../features/themeMode/themeModeSlice";
import liveGeneralStatisticsReducer from "../features/liveGeneralStatistics/liveGeneralStatisticsSlice";
import betsReducer from "../features/bets/betsSlice";

export default configureStore({
  reducer: {
    themeMode: themeModeReducer,
    liveGeneralStatistics: liveGeneralStatisticsReducer,
    betsReducer: betsReducer,
  },
});
```

And in the component I'm calling at the beginning, as usually:

```
const betsRedux = useSelector(getBets);
```

But, unexpectedly, on render, I get:
**TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of undefined**

Pointing at:

```
  16 |  * Exporting to avoid boilerplate like:
  17 |  * const count = useSelector((state) => state.counter.value)
  18 |  */
> 19 | export const getBets = (state) => state.bets.value;
  20 | 
  21 | export default betsSlice.reducer;
  22 |
```

I don't understand why is this happening, given that we have the initialState setup.

What would be the way to solve this, please?

Comment: Can you show your store setup file with the `configureStore` call?

Comment: You must be having a different key (not `bets`) for this reducer when configuring the store. Don't be confused with slice-name as it is the prefix value for the generated action types. See [createSlice#name](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/api/createSlice#name). You should write: `bets: betsReducer` instead of `betsReducer: betsReducer`.

Comment: Thanks a lot @markerikson and Ajeet Shah - yes, I had "betsReducer: betsReducer", as you can now see in the updated question. Thanks - all works now. :)

Answer (score 4):

`configureStore` use [combineReducers(reducers)](https://redux.js.org/api/combinereducers) underhood:

> You can control state key names by using different keys for the reducers in the passed object. For example, you may call `combineReducers({ todos: myTodosReducer, counter: myCounterReducer }) for the state shape to be { todos, counter }`.

In your case, you should replace the `betsReducer` key with `bets` like this:

```js
export default configureStore({
  reducer: {
    themeMode: themeModeReducer,
    liveGeneralStatistics: liveGeneralStatisticsReducer,
    bets: betsReducer,
  },
});
```

The state shape will be: `{ themeMode, liveGeneralStatistics, bets }`

Then, the `export const getBets = (state) => state.bets.value;` selector will work.